# Camera capture not scaling properly?

Tags: coronasdk

In my application i have to take image via media .show(). but image not scaling properly.please help me i did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the image on the screen you can either use:

```
image:scale(xscale, yscale)
```

or

```
image.xScale = scale
image.yScale = scale
```

to resize the image to fit the area you need it.  What "scale" is depends on what you're trying to do, but lets say you want to show the whole image on the screen:

```
 scale = display.contentWidth  / image.width
 image.xScale = scale
 image.yScale = scale
```

or something like that.